# Why hasn't Missouri officially allocated its remaining delegates to Donald Trump yet?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, republican-primary, missouri

Why hasn't Missouri officially allocated its remaining delegates to Donald Trump yet? He won,  didn't he?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Missouri Republican party](https://www.missouri.gop/election-2016/#delegates), they have awarded Trump 37 delegates and Cruz 15.  That's all 52.

> Because no candidate won more than 50% of the votes cast, Missouri’s 52 delegates were allocated to the top vote-getter in each Congressional District with a bonus to the top vote-getter statewide.
>
> The following candidates won delegates in Missouri:
>
> **Donald Trump: 37** (12 for the statewide win, 5 each for Congressional Districts 1, 2, 3, 6 & 8)
>
> **Ted Cruz: 15** (5 each for Congressional Districts 4, 5, and 7)

It says that the Missouri Secretary of State has not certified the results.  Perhaps another source is waiting for that to occur.